# How to enable chuncking on Apache 2.2.3 on Redhat system

Tags: apache, redhat, mod-deflate, chunking

My Apache (version 2.2.3 on redhat) server doesn't accept chunked-encoding, throwing this error:

`chunked Transfer-Encoding forbidden: /services/soap`.

I saw some people have the same problem, they suggested disabling the mod_deflate.so, I commented that line:

`#LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so`

and restarted Apache, but still I have the same problem.

What do I miss?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add this:

`WSGIChunkedRequest On`

Now it works with `mod_deflate` disabled.